# Set cursor position in android Edit text

Tags: android, android-edittext

How can i set the cursor position in android edit text? I have an edit text and on create i want to set the cursor to some times in the end some times in the middle of the text, what can i do?

my edit text is as follows:

```
android:id="@+id/editText11"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="200sp"
android:layout_above="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:gravity="top"
android:background="#00000000"
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
android:singleLine="true"
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can achieve this by using :

```
Edittext.setSelection(Edittext.length());
```

this will put the cursor position in the end. otherwise you can get the text in a string and check the text position where you want to put the cursor and do it like this

```
String text = edittext.getText().toString();

for(int i = 0; i <text.length();i++)
{
//your logic here to check the position of text
}
```

and then

```
Edittext.setSelection(position);
```

Comment: Any suggestion to set cursor position to end of hint text?

Comment: setSelection() method not available..?

Comment: setSelection() is available, but I am unable move cursor to any position

Comment: It's Selection.setSelection(length) and not EditText.setSelection()

Comment: `Edittext.length()` is unknown. Use `edittext.text.length`.

Answer (score 19):

Position at the **start**

```
editText.setSelection(0);
```

Position at the **end**

```
editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
```

Position at the **middle**

```
editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length() / 2);
```

Comment: Any suggestion to set cursor position to end of hint text?

Comment: @CoDe Why would you ever need that? Whenever user types he will only start the things from the index 0 if you have set any hint.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
editText1.requestFocus(Your_Text.length());
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: The method you mentioned takes in direction and not length. Check [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#requestfocus) out

Answer (score 1):

```
editText1.setSelection(Your position)
```

or

```
EditText etext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inbox);
etext.setSelection(etext.getText().length());
```