# How to enable cursor for EditText android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

How to enable cursor for EditText if we **already hide** the soft keyboard. i done my code like that **cursor blinking** but cursor can't not perform **cut/copy/paste and deleting** character action.

I enable only cursor i done by using this code

```
EditText mEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.xEt);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {

     mEt.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
     mEt.setTextIsSelectable(true);

} else {

    mEt.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
    mEt.setFocusable(true);

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Briefly, all you have to do is call:

```
editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
```

for your EditText view (after you called ).

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

You should probably also set:

```
editText.setTextIsSelectable(true);
```

Comment: same result not change by using .setTextIsSelectable(true);

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using :

```
Edittext.setSelection(Edittext.length());
```

this will put the cursor position in the end. otherwise you can get the text in a string and check the text position where you want to put the cursor and do it like this

```
String text = edittext.gettext.tostring()

for(int i = 0; i <text.length();i++)
{
//your logic here to check the position of text
}
```

and then

```
Edittext.setSelection(position);
```

[Reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20838227/set-cursor-position-in-android-edit-text)

Comment: actually i need default clipboard  that appear on top of where EditText or copy text..

Answer (score 0):

You can use it :-)

```
editText.setCursorVisible(true);
```

Happy Coding :-)