# How to set the cursor to the editText

Tags: java, android

I have two EditText, how can I set the cursor in the right EditText

```
 EditText emailE = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmailLogin);
 EditText passwordE = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextPasswordLogin);
 String email = emailE.getText().toString().trim();
 String password = passwordE.getText().toString().trim();
```

if the user pressing Singin and the email EditText is empty, set the cursor in the email EditText.
and the same for password EditText

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
        Toast.makeText(this, getResources()"email is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //set cursor in Email editText
        emailE.setSelection(0);
        return;
    }
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
        Toast.makeText(this,"password is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //set cursor in Password editText
       passwordE.setSelection(0);
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use **requestFocus();** method of edittext like this

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
    Toast.makeText(this, getResources()"email is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //set cursor in Email editText
    emailE.requestFocus();
    return;
}
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
    Toast.makeText(this,"password is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //set cursor in Password editText
   passwordE.requestFocus();
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `.requestFocus();` method

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
        Toast.makeText(this, getResources()"email is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //set cursor in Email editText
        emailE.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
        Toast.makeText(this,"password is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //set cursor in Password editText
       passwordE.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
etext1.setSelection(Your position)
```

or

```
 EditText etext1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etext1 );
    etext1.setSelection(etext1.getText().length());
```

or

```
etext1 .requestFocus(Your_Text.length());
```

Try this one also;
[Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20838227/set-cursor-position-in-android-edit-text/20838294#20838294)

Answer (score 1):

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myTextViewId);


if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
    Toast.makeText(this, getResources()"email is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //set cursor in Email editText
    emailE.requestFocus();
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.showSoftInput(emailE, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    return;
}
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
    Toast.makeText(this,"password is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //set cursor in Password editText
    passwordE.requestFocus();
    InputMethodManager imm2 = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm2.showSoftInput(passwordE, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    return;
}
```