# How to add a Character to an EditText where the User's Cursor is

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I want the user to be able to press a button and add a certain character such as "<", and after the character is added in the position the cursor is, I want the cursor to move to after the added character, like he presses it on his keyboard.

If I just save the current content of the EditText and add a character it will just add it to the end, and will reset the position of the cursor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try doing something as follows:

```
EditText edittext = findViewById(R.id.edittext);
Button button = findViewById(R.id.button)b

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int cursorPosition = edittext.getSelectionStart();
                String enteredText = edittext.getText().toString();
                String startToCursor = enteredText.subSequence(0, cursorPosition);
                String cursorToEnd = enteredText.subSequence(cursorPosition, enteredText.length());

                String finalString = startToCursor + "<" + cursorToEnd;
                edittext.setText(finalString);
                edittext.setSelection(cursorPosition+1);
            )
});
```

References: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6900610/10487248 ,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20838294/10487248